# converting a tuple with multiple elements to a string in a list

Tags: python

What would be an easy way to convert:

```
(1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

to

```
['100000']
```

I know how to switch it to a list using

```
list()
```

but i can't figure out how to combine the elements into a string and keep that inside a list.

Comment: `[''.join(map(str, (1,0,0,0,0,0)))]`

Answer (score 0):

`sep.join(strlist)` joins a list of strings together using `sep` as a separator.

In this case, you will have three steps:

1. Convert the list of ints to a list of strs, which can be accomplished like so:
   `strlist = map(str, intlist)`
2. Convert the list of strings to a single string using `join`.
   `intstring = "".join(strlist)`

   Setting the separator = `""` will make it squish together to  a single string.
3. Convert the string to a list with a string:
   `final = [intstring]`

Or in one line, as in falsetru's comment:

`[''.join(map(str, digits))]`